# How to transform a item set matrix in R

Tags: r

How to transform a matrix like

```
A 1 2 3
B 3 6 9
c 5 6 9
D 1 2 4
```

into form like:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1  0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
2  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  
3  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1    
4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0      
5  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1           
6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2         
7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0           
8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0               
9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have some implement for it ,but it use the for loop
I wonder if there has some inner function in R (for example "apply")

add:
Sorry for the confusion.The first matrix just mean items sets, every set of items come out pairs ,for example the first set is "1 2 3" , and will become (1,2),(1,3),(2,3), correspond the second matrix.

and another question :
If the matrix is very large (10000000*10000000)and is sparse
should I use sparse matrix or big.matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: How are your two matrices related? What is meant by your first matrix?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.The first matrix just mean items sets, every set of items  come out pairs ,for example the first set is "1 2 3" , and will become (1,2),(1,3),(2,3), correspond the second matrix.

Comment: @heyflypig welcome to SO.  cool question!  hopefully downvoters will change their vote once they see your edit  :)

Comment: @Anthony Damico This is my first question in stackoverflow, hope it won't confuse someone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the row names from M gives this:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,3,5,1,2,6,6,2,3,9,9,4), nrow=4)

> m
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    2    3
## [2,]    3    6    9
## [3,]    5    6    9
## [4,]    1    2    4

# The indicies that you want to increment in x, but some are repeated
# combn() is used to compute the combinations of columns
indices <- matrix(t(m[,combn(1:3,2)]),,2,byrow=TRUE)

# Count repeated rows
ones <- rep(1,nrow(indices))
cnt <-  aggregate(ones, by=as.data.frame(indices), FUN=sum)

# Set each value to the appropriate count
x <- matrix(0, 9, 9)
x[as.matrix(cnt[,1:2])] <- cnt[,3]

x

##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
##  [1,]    0    2    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
##  [2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
##  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
##  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
##  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2
##  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
##  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```